# Time frame for editing a Facebook comment

Tags: facebook

I noticed earlier today that immediately after entering the comment I can edit the comment. Is there a specified time frame that one can perform edits ?

Does this also work for multiple comments in quick succession ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time frame for editing on comments is about 60 seconds. There is one caveat though, if a comment is posted after yours then the editing functionality is disabled. You can still delete the comment but not edit it.

Notifications are send for the original comment and any edits made.

Links:

[TechZoom article](http://techzoom.org/facebook-new-feature-now-you-can-edit-facebook-comments/)

[Facebook Known Issues](https://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues/posts/217418684936503)

Comment: Also Facebook mentioned it [here](https://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues/posts/217418684936503).

Comment: @mark4o: Nice link - I'll add it to my answer.